# I have the following problem and am not able to post on the forums

Tags: php

Error in posting

DEBUG MODE

SQL Error : 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

INSERT INTO nuke_bbtopics (topic_title, topic_poster, topic_time, forum_id, topic_status, topic_type, topic_vote) VALUES ('Test', 39, 1541598387, 22, 0, 0, 0)

Line : 227
File : functions_post.php

Answer (score 0):

You have problems not in query, but in table sequence. Just reorder autoincrement.

Answer (score 0):

Your autoincrement is not orderd. check if you have your `PRIMARY_KEY` on `AUTO_INCREMENT,`.

Comment: For some reason it was not but is now. Success, thank you :)